# Проблема компиляции Cosmos C#

Tags: c#

Решил тут написать ОС.
Поставил VS 2013 и Cosmos User Kit. Ошибка, я так понимаю, не моя, а Cosmos'а
Мой код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Sys = Cosmos.System;

namespace Meduze
{
    public class Kernel : Sys.Kernel
    {
        protected override void BeforeRun()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Meduze starting...");
        }

        protected override void Run()
        {
            while(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Meduze, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------  
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Cosmos.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5ae71220097cb983, processorArchitecture=MSIL", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.  
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Cosmos.Debug.Kernel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5ae71220097cb983, processorArchitecture=MSIL", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.  
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Cosmos.Hardware, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5ae71220097cb983, processorArchitecture=MSIL", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.  
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Cosmos.System, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5ae71220097cb983, processorArchitecture=MSIL", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.  
1>  Meduze -> c:\users\катя\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Meduze\Meduze\bin\Debug\Meduze.dll  
2>------ Build started: Project: MeduzeBoot, Configuration: Debug x86 ------  
2>  IL2CPU invoked with DebugMode='Source', DebugEnabled='True', TraceAssemblies='{NULL}', IgnoreDebugStub='False'  
2>  IL2CPU task took 00:00:18.0546475  
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Cosmos\Cosmos.targets(55,5): error : Error occurred while invoking objdump.  
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Cosmos\Cosmos.targets(55,5): error : An error occurred: System.ArgumentNullException: Parameter "message" cannot be null.  
2>   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowArgumentNull(Object parameter, String parameterName, String resourceName)  
2>   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TaskLoggingHelper.LogError(String subcategory, String errorCode, String helpKeyword, String file, Int32 lineNumber, Int32 columnNumber, Int32 endLineNumber, Int32 endColumnNumber, String message, Object[] messageArgs)  
2>   at Cosmos.Build.MSBuild.BaseToolTask.Logs(LogInfo logInfo) in g:\IL2CPU\source2\Build\Cosmos.Build.MSBuild\BaseToolTask.cs:line 175  
2>   at Cosmos.Build.MSBuild.BaseToolTask.ExecuteTool(String workingDir, String filename, String arguments, String name) in g:\IL2CPU\source2\Build\Cosmos.Build.MSBuild\BaseToolTask.cs:line 127  
2>   at Cosmos.Build.MSBuild.ExtractMapFromElfFile.RunObjDump() in g:\IL2CPU\source2\Build\Cosmos.Build.MSBuild\ExtractMapFromElfFile.cs:line 174  
2>   at Cosmos.Build.MSBuild.ExtractMapFromElfFile.Execute() in g:\IL2CPU\source2\Build\Cosmos.Build.MSBuild\ExtractMapFromElfFile.cs:line 68  
2>Done building project "MeduzeBoot.Cosmos" -- FAILED.  
2>  
Build has been canceled.
```

Почему возникает ошибка и как её исправить?

Comment: а в чём заключается ваш вопрос?

Comment: Почему возникает ошибка и как её исправить?

Comment: пожалуйста, впишите эту информацию в текст самого вопроса, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ваш проект лежит в:

> c:\users\катя\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Meduze\

Попробуйте разместить его в другой директории, так, чтобы путь не содержал кириллицы. Cosmos не поддерживает не ASCII символы в путях.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Но очень странно, ведь обычные проекты (не cosmos) могут находится в пути с кириллицей.

Comment: @Андрей это ограничение именно Cosmos'а. С некоторыми программами такое случается :). Если помогло, можете отметить ответ как верный.